# X11 Forwarding: Bad File Number Error?

Tags: linux, ssh, cygwin, x11

I have XWin Server running on my local computer (Windows 7). When I open up a cygwin shell and type emacs, a graphical display for emacs comes up as expected.
Now I try to get a remote application to display on my local machine. In cygwin, I type:

```
ssh -X root@.....
```

(I have also tried **ssh -Y root@...** with the same results.) I log in with the password and then I get this fun message:

```
/usr/bin/xauth:  creating new authority file /root/.Xauthority
```

Then I try to open xeyes. This is the point where I expect a window to pop up on my local machine with googly eyes that follow the mouse cursor. Instead I get some cryptic error message:

```
root@debian:~# xeyes
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: Bad file number
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

This is the extent of my troubleshooting capabilities on Linux:

```
root@debian:~# echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

I am very new to Linux. How can I get the remote server to know about my local XWin Server? It seems like it should be simple, since I already have a connection through ssh.

**Update**
So I guess cygwin has this "feature" where if you set the DISPLAY to :0, it means something different than localhost:0. Setting the DISPLAY to 127.0.0.1:0 or localhost:0 as suggested will fix the problem.

Comment: Not sure it will solve your problem, but you might want to enable trusted X11 forwarding with `ssh -Y root@...`

Comment: echo $DISPLAY outputs localhost:10.0 when I am ssh'ed into the remote server.

Comment: This probably belongs under serverfault, just fyi

Comment: You should allow X11 forwarding on the remote machine, see `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (or whatever it is in your distro). And this definitely belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using XWin outside of Cygwin, which might be causing issues. Try setting your DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0, as suggested here:

http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-xfree/2002-10/msg00065.html

under "Using Cygwin's OpenSSH with XWin-32"

Comment: Err, correction: XWin is part of Cygwin, don't know why I said otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 error messages here. The first one is because SSH client cannot connect to your X display at all on your local machine (/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 means :0). And that causes the second error on the serverside. What happens if you run cygwin xeyes locally?

Comment: Running xeyes locally causes googly eyes to appear on my desktop.

Comment: I don't understand why SSH cannot connect to my display. SSH is running locally, as is the XWin server. If a local program like xeyes can talk to XWin, shouldn't SSH be able to?

Comment: It is indeed strange, you might want to try these at http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-ssh-no-x11forwarding, and/or try update cygwin.